# Does apt install recommends for package childs?

Tags: apt

E.g. package `hollywood` has dependency `byobu` and recommended package `atop`, while `atop` has rec. `cron` and `byobu`, resp. — `less`. Are both `cron` and `less` going to be installed along with `hollywood` depends and recommends?

```
hollywood
|- [dep] byobu
|  |- [rec] less
|
|- [rec] atop
|  |- [rec] cron
```

```
$ sudo apt install -o APT::Install-Recommends="true" hollywood
```

```
$ cat /etc/apt/apt.conf
(...)
APT::Install-Recommends "false";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule is that, if `Install-Recommends` is enabled, then newly-installed packages’ recommendations are themselves considered for installation, and this applies transitively — a newly-installed package selected because of a recommendation will have its own recommendations considered for installation.

Other considerations might however prevent a recommendation from being installed, and because it’s only a recommendation, this won’t be considered a fatal error. In the `hollywood` example, `run-one` will be considered for installation, but on Debian it won’t be installed because the package is not available (it’s a Ubuntu package). Likewise, if a recommended package conflicts with an already-installed package, it won’t be installed. Any further dependencies or recommendations of such a package won’t be considered either.

All this applies during all `apt` operations: `install` obviously, but also `upgrade`. If a package upgrade introduces a new dependency which isn’t already installed, that package will be installed, and the handling of newly-installed packages described above will be applied. On the other hand, package upgrades introducing new recommendations won’t result in extra installations, since the recommendations aren’t defined on newly-*installed* packages.

Comment: To sum up, `apt` "loops", searching for rec's and installs them? With all the "newly installed" considerations.

Comment: Yes, that’s a good summary.

Comment: By any chance, if there is a ready-to-use option to apply the rule only for first-level rec's?

Comment: Not that I’m aware of.

Comment: I can't believe I missed `run-one` is not in the archive.  Thanks for figuring that out.

Answer (score 1):

On my system I already have `less`, so let's think about `run-one` instead.

```
hollywood
|- [dep] byobu
|  |- [rec] run-one
|
|- [rec] atop
|  |- [rec] cron
```

Then when I try to install (removed uninteresting packages from text):

```
$ sudo apt install -o APT::Install-Recommends="true" hollywood
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  atop byobu cron
Recommended packages:
  run-one
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  atop byobu cron hollywood
```

It appears that `apt` does the following:

- `byobu`(dep) is installed, but its recommended package `run-one` is still only recommended.
- `atop` (rec) is installed and its recommended package: `cron | cron-daemon` is installed.

To to generalize, what we just observed when using this option is:

- Recommendations of the package are installed
- Recommendations of the package's dependencies are **not** installed.
- Recommendations of the package's recommendations are installed.

It surprised me that a recommendation of a recommendation would be installed.  I confirmed that `cron` is not a dependency of one of the other packages which would have been installed.

Comment: The reason `run-one` is not installed is that it’s not available in Debian; it’s a Ubuntu package. If `Install-Recommends` is true, all recommendations are installed when possible, cascading down the dependency tree, but stopping when an already-present package is installed — here, if `atop` were already installed, but not `cron`, `cron` would not be considered.

Comment: This also applies on upgrades, with an additional subtlety: upgraded packages’ recommendations aren’t considered, but newly-installed packages’ are. So if an upgraded package adds a *dependency*, which isn’t already present, and `Install-Recommends` is enabled, that new dependency’s recommendations will also be installed.

Comment: @StephenKitt so dependency's recommendations **are** always installed, except e.g. the Ubuntu force majeure (2nd statement)?

Comment: @chzzh if `Install-Recommends` is enabled, yes, during package *installation* (as opposed to upgrade). There can be other “forces majeures”, for example a recommended package which conflicts with an already-installed package.

Comment: I thought I’d only comment since Stewart’s answer was close to the mark already, and quite good, but it seems it’s all a bit too complicated for comments; I’ll write an answer...